# Vertical Alignment isn't quite right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically align a logo and UL within a navigation bar. I've got pretty close and it looks fine really, however there is some extra space underneath and above them both that I can't account for. I've set the padding on the links and logo to allow the user to be able to click them more easily.

Place the mouse underneath the logo and underneath the nav bar, I've tried to do it so that as soon as your mouse reaches the nav bar, it hits the padding of the logo and therefore the mouse cursor turns to pointer. However, there is a gap there...using the developer tools, I can see that it's the div.inner element...but it says it has a margin. I've tried setting the margin to 0 on that div and it doesn't go away.

Here is the jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Forresty/0smpmsqn/2/

I'm using the same vertical alignment method as here: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-holy-grail-of-css-centering--cms-22114

Here is the HTML:

```
<nav>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="logo1">LOGO</div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="border">About</a></li>                    
                <li><a href="#" class="border">My Work</a></li>                    
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Or even if it's not possible to get rid of that extra space, an explanation of why it's there would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```
Display: table-cell;
```

To align in the middle use

line-height | Margin | Padding

The display table cell add's the space

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, What I'm wanting to do it have the padding of the logo touch the bottom of the nav bar. At the moment, it doesn't and I'm wondering why. I want to keep the padding as it is for now.

Comment: Like I said, its the display: table-cell that makes it impossible. Remove it and correct the heigth difference by padding

Comment: Thanks PieterSchool, that's what that extra space was. This seems like so much work just to vertically align something in a div. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the following:

```
 .outer {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;/*set padding to 0*/
}

.logo1 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: dan_custom-font;
    font-size: 2em;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.3em;/*replace padding with margin*/
    margin-left: 0.7em;/*set a bit more margin left*/
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #de1b1b;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: color .3s;
    transition: color .3s;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0smpmsqn/4/)

You can set `.outer` class `padding: 0` and replace `margin` with `padding` in `.logo1`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, What I'm wanting to do is have the padding of the logo touch the bottom of the nav bar. At the moment, it doesn't and I'm wondering why. I want to keep the padding as it is for now. Setting `padding: 0` on `.outer` didn't seem to do anything?

Comment: @Forrest check my fiddle in comment please.

Comment: That is what I mean yes, however the links on the right hand side seem messed up.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/0smpmsqn/8/ please and tell me if is ok or i will delete this answer.

Comment: This is another great way of doing it. I didn't think to set the ul and logo to `display: table-cell;`. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Is there anyway to add a margin to the left of the logo though? Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options.

1. Adjust the height of the nav so that it fit the logo and ul.
2. Adjust the padding of the logo and ul so that it fits the nav.

To see whether they fit, first set a background color for logo and the ul and check.